# How can I add a "second url" to my current one?

Tags: html

I'm creating a website, and I have some trouble configuring my domain. What I mean by that is, I have the domain (myurl.com). How can I make it so that the URL (example.myurl.com) redirects to myurl.com? It would be greatly appreciated.

(google sites)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your web server. If its apache, look into name based virtual host,  ServerName and ServerAlias.

You also need to configure your DNS. You can also use a PTR or CNAME (canonical name) to point lets say [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) to mydomain.com. You can add as many of these in DNS (Name Server) as you well please.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a sub-domain.
I couldn't tell you off hand how to set it up, but hopefully that helps you refine your google searches on the matter.